# Enforce path type without regarding optional attributes

Tags: typescript

I am writing a helper function that sets a value in an object at a `path` like so

```
function set<
    C extends Collection<any>,
    E = C extends Collection<infer U> ? U : never,
    K1 extends keyof E = keyof E,
    K2 extends keyof E[K1]= keyof E[K1]
    V extends E[K1][K2]= E[K1][K2]
>(
  collection: C, 
  entityId: string, 
  path: [K1, K2], 
  value: V
)
```

This allows me to do the following

```
Collection.set(myCommentCollection, someComment.id, ['author', 'name'], 'jack');
```

The above works great, as long as neither `author` or `name` attributes are optional, in which case the compiler with complain with

```
Argument of type '["author", string]' is not assignable to parameter of type '["author", never]'.
```

What I want to achieve is that the compiler only enforces that the path is valid. ie. each attribute in the path is correctly defined, disregarding whether or not they're optional.

As part of the function implementation I'll just return early if the full path is not defined.

Is this possible? Thanks

UPDATE

If the `stats` is required and the `total` attribute is optional, the below will fail

```
Collection.set(myCollection, someItem.id, ['stats', 'total'], 10)
```

Error:

```
Argument of type '[number, "total"]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[never, "total"]'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Comment: You just need this for a maximum of 2 levels ?

Comment: This is a simplified version, i also have cases for 1, 2 and 3 levels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that for optional fields of the interface the type for a field will be `TField|undefined`. For union types as usual we only have access to common fields, so this means that none of the fields o `TField` will appear in `keyof TField|undefined`, as this `TField` will have nothing in common with `undefined`.

We can use a predefined conditional type to remove `undefined` from the field type:

```
function set<
    C extends Collection<any>,
    E = C extends Collection<infer U> ? U : never,
    K1 extends keyof E = keyof E,
    V1 = Exclude<E[K1], undefined>,
    K2 extends keyof V1= keyof V1,
    V2 extends V1[K2] =V1[K2]
>(
collection: C, 
entityId: string, 
path: [K1, K2], 
value: V2
) {}

//Usage 

interface Comment extends Entity {
    author?: {
        name?: string
    }
    stats : {
        total?: number
    }
}
export interface Collection<T extends Entity> extends Object {
    readonly entities: { [key: string]: T };
    readonly ids: EntityId[];
}
set(commentState, comment.id, ['author', 'name'], 'jack'); //OK
set(commentState, comment.id, ['stats', 'total'], 10); //OK
```

Comment: This works almost perfect, but it will fail when only the last fragment of the path is conditional, ie. the example below will fail if the `total` attribute is optional

`Collection.set(myCollection, itemId, ['stats', 'total'], 10)`

Comment: @Tarlen could you post a more complete failing example ?

Comment: Updated example

Comment: @Tarlen I am unable to reproduce your error as you describe it. I updated with my testing code.

Comment: Ah, It was because I had missed the return type of the function and I was chaining the results of one call to another. Added return type now and it works. Thank you so much for the help and intuition behind